# relocation entry is not shown in objdump output of given sample program

Tags: c, linker, objdump

I have the below sample code. I would like to see the relocation table entries from the object file. For this, i have used

```
objdump -r test.o
```

Sample Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char * myfunction ();
int x=20;
int main()
{

  printf (" \n Inside main ");
  char * p = myfunction ();
  printf (" \n My string is %s ", p);
}

char * myfunction ()
{
  char * key ="jaka";
  return key;
}
```

Outputof Objdump -r test.o

```
test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000000009 R_X86_64_32       .rodata
0000000000000013 R_X86_64_PC32     printf-0x0000000000000004
000000000000001d R_X86_64_PC32     myfunction-0x0000000000000004
000000000000002d R_X86_64_32       .rodata+0x0000000000000010
0000000000000037 R_X86_64_PC32     printf-0x0000000000000004
0000000000000045 R_X86_64_32S      .rodata+0x0000000000000024


RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.eh_frame]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000000020 R_X86_64_PC32     .text
0000000000000040 R_X86_64_PC32     .text+0x000000000000003d
```

**QUESTION:**

According to my understanding the global variable 'x' should have been in the relocation table somewhere, which i m unable to locate.

Please help me if i overlooked something here ?

Answer (score 2):

There are shouldn't be any relocation entries related to `x` because your code doesn't use it. Nevertheless it presents in symbol table, and you can check it with `objdump -t`

Saying in few words - relocation entry is the thing that helps your code to reference to some object, to link against them. So, if you don't reference `x` in your code - there won't be any `x` targeted relocations.

To check it - add, for example, `x = 40;` in the `main()` and you'll get the next:

```
test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000000009 R_X86_64_32       .rodata
0000000000000013 R_X86_64_PC32     printf-0x0000000000000004
000000000000001d R_X86_64_PC32     myfunction-0x0000000000000004
000000000000002d R_X86_64_32       .rodata+0x0000000000000010
0000000000000037 R_X86_64_PC32     printf-0x0000000000000004
000000000000003d R_X86_64_PC32     x-0x0000000000000008         # bingo!
000000000000004f R_X86_64_32S      .rodata+0x0000000000000024


RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.eh_frame]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000000020 R_X86_64_PC32     .text
0000000000000040 R_X86_64_PC32     .text+0x0000000000000047
```